# trouble with alert message

Tags: javascript, swift, xcode

i am trying to get the "password missing" working when i dont type same password and i try to get "helo fill everything" working for when no answers has been given.

problem is that it jumps right over the first 2 statements and then down to the last alert "AAAAA".. (sorry for the first part of code..)

```
if(userPassword != userPasswordRepeat)
    {           
        displayAlertMessage(alarm: ("password missing"));
        return
    }
    if(userEmail == "" || userPassword == "" || userFirstName == "" || userLastName == "")
    {
        //vis alarm besked 2
        displayAlertMessage(alarm: ("helo fill everyting"));
        return
    }        

}
func displayAlertMessage(alarm:String)
{
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "AAAAA", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)


    myAlert.addAction(okAction);


    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

`

Comment: I don't know swift or xcode, but it seems the  `displayAlertMessage()` function ignores its `alarm` argument and just uses a hard-coded "AAAAA". Also, you've got unbalanced curly brackets (too many closing `}`).

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Your alert controller's message is "AAAAA" isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

using param `alarm` instead of `AAAAA`

```
let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: alarm, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems your `alarm` string in `displayAlertMessage(alarm:String)` is never used, try following code

```
func displayAlertMessage(alarm:String){
   //check alarm valid then use it, otherwise use default hint string
   let hintStr = alarm.characters.count > 0 ? alarm : "AAAAA"

   let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: hintStr, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

   let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)


   myAlert.addAction(okAction);


   self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your copy & paste. You've got too many unbalanced curly brackets.
If you want to display the message, you have to send it to the function as an argument.

Here is the code:

```
if(userPassword != userPasswordRepeat)
    {           
        displayAlertMessage(alarm: "password missing");
        return
    }
    if(userEmail == "" || userPassword == "" || userFirstName == "" || userLastName == "")
    {
        //vis alarm besked 2
        displayAlertMessage(alarm: "helo fill everyting");
        return
    }        


func displayAlertMessage(alarm:String)
{
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: alarm, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)


    myAlert.addAction(okAction);


    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```